# How to clear command history in Octave

Tags: octave

What command can I use to clear the history that appears in the lower left-hand corner of the Octave IDE?

Comment: I would like to know why you haven't found this yourself. If you type `help history` you'll see "'-c' Clear the history list." Also if you google for "gnu octave clear history" the first hit would show you how

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the [documentation for `history`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Commands-for-History.html#index-history-2), you can use the `-c` flag to clear the current history

```
history -c
```

Answer (score -1):

The below command will be handy.

```
   clc; history -c
```

Comment: `clc` is irrelevant here. Rest is already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949428/5698672) by [Suever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670206/). Please read the already posted answers before posting yours.